# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in winform when binding a datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

You may laugh at me stupid, you may vote down. But it is okay. I have struggled this simple question for several days. Basically I want to display a table through datagridview in windows form. The table is got from a stored procedure.

```
BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    private SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable table1 =  some subroutine
```

Then table does exists.
[image: snapshot]

Then after run the code below I got an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

```
ds.Tables.Add(table1);
            da.Fill(table1); // here catch an error.
            bsource.DataSource = table1;
            datagridview1.DataSource = table1;
```

Comment: What your subroutine returns??

Comment: Have you created a new instance of the DataAdapter? please paste all the code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are initializing `da` somewhere, between this:

```
private SqlDataAdapter da;
```

and this:

```
da.Fill(table1);
```

you will of course get an NPE because it's not pointing to anything. I think you meant:

```
private SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
```

Comment: @Habib.OSU: Class members default to null, so in this case it will not signal an error. If `da` was a method local variable then it would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing `SqlDataAdapter`

```
private SqlDataAdapter da = // Initialize adapter here.
```